# On OSX grep can I use look ahead?

Tags: command-line, macos

This works:

```
$ echo "$Foo" | grep "Android SDK Build-tools" | grep -Eo "\d+(?:-)"
4-
5-
6-
7-
8-
9-
```

This does not:

```
$ echo "$Foo" | grep "Android SDK Build-tools" | grep -Eo "\d+(?=-)"
grep: repetition-operator operand invalid
```

Can I use lookahead if I want to with the OSX supplied version of grep?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

grep in macOS does not support lookahead. For more information about the regex syntax supported in the default macOS binaries, see [re_format(7)](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/re_format.7.html).

If you need to use such a regex, you can install GNU grep with Homebrew (`brew install grep` then use `ggrep`) and use the -P option to enable Perl regex syntax which does support your regex.

Comment: Note if you're writing scripts to work with a vanilla install of macOS `[[ "$OSTYPE == darwin* ]]` you should make it work with BSD grep and not expect the user to have GNU grep installed already.